# While using the CGContextFillRects,CGContextAddPath and CGContextSetFillColorWithColor getting crashed in iOS 7.1

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-graphics

I'm getting the following error message while using the `CGContextFillRects`,`CGContextAddPath` and `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor`.

`CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0`.

```
CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(); 
unsigned char resultingPixel[4]; 
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(&resultingPixel, 1, 1, 8, 4, rgbColorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast); 
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]); 
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1));
CGContextRelease(context); 
CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace);
```

Comment: code, buddy, show your code

Comment: CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    unsigned char resultingPixel[4];
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(&resultingPixel, 1, 1, 8, 4, rgbColorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1));
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace);

Comment: do not put the code in the comments. put it in your own question

Comment: Did you get any suggestion with issue which respect to above mentioned code.